# Why did Hanne choose not to pursue them?

Tags: plot-explanation, who-am-i-2014

In the ending of [Who Am I - Kein System ist sicher](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3042408/), after Hanne Lindberg found out about the trick of Benjamin and his three other teammates (the sugar cube trick), why did she choose not to pursue them? Is it because she believed that Benjamin is not bad and won't do it again or did she just not have the ability to do so? In the ending scene, she seems pleased that Benjamin got away though...

Comment: Or maybe she is the mental ill person. That's why Benjamin appear with his hair dyed like Hannah's.

Answer (score -1):

She got her reputation back because of Benjamin which made her okay with that Benjamin cheated.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on your answer?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34995)

Comment: This does provide an answer. It is not a comment or reply. It may be low quality, but it is a direct answer to the question @MattD

Comment: @cde Which is why my initial comment notes that elaboration is needed for it to be a quality answer. You'll note (unless only I can see it) that the second comment is an automatic one based on site review, for which you are the sole person feeling this answer is okay.

Comment: @MattD there are multiple choices on the review for recommend deletion, and none of them fit this. The provided one specifically doesn't fit this. Deletion is for non-answers, i.e. spam, offensive, comments, replies. Bad/Wrong/Inaccurate answers should be down voted, not deleted. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141851/reviewing-low-quality-posts-when-to-delete and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing and http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers . This answers the question.

Comment: How does it answer the question? It has nothing to back it up and merely provides a statement. It elaborates on nothing, nor provides any further detail to actually back the statement as factual. To me this makes it more of a non-answer as it really doesn't provide any substance, value, or evidence to back it up. It is merely a statement, ergo it's more a comment than an answer.

Comment: @MattD http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1206/what-is-a-low-quality-answer/1207#1207 ***[ANS] Note that wrong answers should not be deleted: deletion is for answers that “aren't even wrong”.***

Comment: Close voting is a communal effort, and you are the lone dissenting voice when it comes to this answer.

Comment: @Mattd No, he isn't. It's true that the answer isn't particularly elaborate, but it *is* an answer (even a correct one, but disregarding that).